# How can I store the imagePath of the image that I took using the camera activity into the database and retrieving the path?

Tags: android, database, android-image

how to store the imagePath of the image that I had captured using the camera activity to database. I also need to retrieve that imagePath and display on another activity? 
Can someone help me please?

*Update:*

```
public class Image_secondPage extends Activity 
{
    public static final int CAMERA_RESULT = 1;
    Button btn1;
    ImageView imageView1;
    private final String tag = getClass().getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_secondpage);


        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
     btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Image_secondPage.this, ImagesPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(tag, "Receive the camera result");
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT)
        {
            File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
            if(!out.exists())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error while capturing image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        imageView1 = null;
    }
```

I am supposed to get the imagePath that I have captured and show the image on the imageView that I had on the next class but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

Comment: How are you capturing image? show us code..

Comment: I have posted the codes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this

```
bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

this will give you bitmap image, then you can save it to database or anything you want.

let me know if this not solve your problem.

Comment: eh insert this line at which part of the coding?

Comment: replace this  Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Okayy. Can tell me what is the difference between the 2 codes? I edited but still don't know what they do.

Comment: i dont understand what you do inside onActivityResult method, but i know that u want to display an image after capturing it from camera, right? you can get that image with this "data.getExtras().get("data")" this code get the data of the image, than cast it to bitmap. so we can place it in a bitmap variable. than show it on an imageview.

Comment: I haven't tested it out on real device cause the emulator can't work. So I don't know whether it worked or not.